# In Java, is there an unmodifiable list class that can not be assigned to List class?

Tags: java

I want to prevent below runtime error:

```
  Exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at ImmutableCollections.uoe (ImmutableCollections.java:142)
```

while adding to an unknown List data type. eg:

```
List<String> fruits = provideFruits();
fruits.add("Cherry");
```

As an alternative, I am looking for a data type that `provideFruits()` can return as an unmodifiable list, but that can not be assigned to `List` class at compile time, so that it prevents this runtime misery!

Comment: Instead of fixing `provideFruits`, fix `fruits.add`. Whoever wrote that should not have assumed the list is modifiable.

Comment: Create custom list class and return that. But there nothing such thing in Java. And I don't see any reason to be it there.

Comment: It's arguably a design flaw, but there's no read-only List interface in the JDK. You can create your own, or use something like Guava's `ImmutableList` which at least deprecates those methods. But the general answer is you have to assume Lists are not mutable unless you know otherwise, like @Sweeper said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `provideFruits();` is returning an immutable list the `fruits` list also will be immutable and you wont be able to add to it.

There are two options

1. Make `providerFruits()` return a mutable list. (*Additional Note just in case*: if you are using streams api to return the results in `providerFruits()`, note that `stream.toList()` will create an immutable list while `stream.collect(toList())` will create mutable lists.)
2. Change your code as follows,

   ```
   List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>(provideFruits());
   fruits.add("Cherry");
   ```

This will ensure `fruits` is mutable even if results of `provideFruits()` is immutable

Comment: regarding the "*Additional Note*" `Collectors#toList` is not guaranteed to return a mutable list - [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()): "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned;"